# Responsive Bootstrap Modal Not Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying my best to make my modal responsive on all screens but still the file input as well as button are not aligning so well when I tried to narrow down my screen esp on the port 800 below.

Contact List  Add New

```
<!-- New Contact Modal -->
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="edit-modal" class="modal fade" id="new-contact-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h2 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center font-weight-bold">New Contact</h2>
              </div>           
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Name:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="email" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Email:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="company" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Mobile:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="phone" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Phone:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Address:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="city" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">City:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="city" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">State:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="city" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Country:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="city" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Zip:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-s12">
                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="group" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Category:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <select name="group" id="group" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Select category</option>
                          <option value="1">Family</option>
                          <option value="2">Friend</option>
                          <option value="3">Other</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" id="add-group-btn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-category-button btn-block mt-0">Add Category</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row" id="add-new-group">
                      <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_id" placeholder="Enter category name" aria-label="Enter category name" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary category-btn" type="button" id="button-addon2">
                              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                      <div class="fileinput-new img-thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"  alt="...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
                      <div class="mt-2">
                        <span class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-button btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-button mb-3 ml-3" id="save-btn">Save</button>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-button mt-n3" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel-btn">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- New Contact Modal -->
```

Here's the CSS [ignore the other stuffs]:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


body{
  font-family: 'Kulim Park', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f9f9f9;

}


a.navbar-brand {
  background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat;
  width: 213px;
  height: 27px;
}

header{
  background-color: #1c1b28;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.6em 0;

}

.navbar a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


span.navbar-toggler-icon{
  color: #fff !important;
}


section#big-hero{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: url('../img/intro-bg.png') center bottom no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 120px 0 120px 0;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

.main-text-white{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.main-text-blue{
  color: #1C1B28;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.sub-text-blue{
  color: #444;
   font-size: 1.1em;
}


#about{
  margin: 2.6em 0;
}


.sub-text-white{
  color: #e2e2e2;
}

.main-btn{
    cursor: pointer !important;

    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    color: #fff;
}


.icon-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.icon-box i {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon-box > p {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.icon-radius {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: #007BFF;
  border-style: solid;
}

.fa {
  color: #007BFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


li.link-button{
   cursor: pointer !important;
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0px 18px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}


li.link-button:hover{
  background-color: #0069D9;
}

.border-button{
    cursor: pointer !important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.add-category-button{
  padding: 6px 13px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}


section#testimonials{
     padding: 3em 0 4.1em 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     background: #ecf5ff;

}

.img-rounded{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.testimonials-name{
  color: #1C1B28;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
}

footer{
    background-color: #1c1b28;
    padding: 1em 0 0.3em 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

footer p{
  color: #e2e2e2;
  font-size: 1em;
}


label{
  font-weight: bold;
}


section.form-box {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86vh;
}

section.form-box .container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.vertical-align {
  max-width: 300px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#arrow-up{
  background: #1C1B28;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 86%;
  left: 91%;
}

.fa-big{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin: 16%;

}

i.fa-big:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#search-bar{
  padding: 3.3em 0 0 0;
}

input.form-control.search-input{
  width: 85%;
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.search-btn{
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  margin-top: 0.6em;
}

#main-content{
  padding: 2em 0 5.3em 0;
}

.white{
  color: #fff;
}

.card-footer{
  padding: 1em 0 0 0;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.badge{
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: #fff;
}

a.list-group-item.active  span.badge{
  background-color: #fff;
   color: #007BFF;
}

.btn-circle{
  width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: #007BFF;
}

.btn-outline-secondary{
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.btn-outline-secondary:hover{
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.fa:hover, .btn-circle:hover .fa{
    color: #fff !important;
}

.btn.focus, .btn:focus, a.page-link:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}


/* File Input style */

.media img, .fileinput .img-thumbnail, .img-thumbnail img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.fileinput .btn {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0.5em 0.6em;
}

.btn-file > input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    font-size: 23px;
    height: 38%;
    width: 100%;
    direction: ltr;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.fileinput-exists .fileinput-new, .fileinput-new .fileinput-exists {
    display: none;
}

/* File Input */



.form-contact{
  padding: 3em 0;
}

button.category-btn{
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

button.category-btn:hover .fa{
  color: #fff;
}

.modal-xl{
  max-width: 50% !important;
}

/* Homepage Media Queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
   #arrow-up{
    left: 85%;
   }

   #get-started{
     margin: 0 auto 20px auto !important;
     text-align: center !important;
   }

      .fileinput-new{
      margin: 10px auto !important;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .border-button.btn-file{
      margin-left: 50px !important;
    }

    .card-footer{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #save-btn{
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


}


@media only screen and (min-width: 988px) {
    .add-category-button{
      font-size: 12px;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
   #arrow-up{
    left: 94%;
   }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 578px) and (max-width: 988px){
   #category-nav{
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 18px !important;
      margin-top: -20px !important;
    }

    #search-form{
      width: 100% !important;
    }

}



@media only screen and (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 570px) {

    #search-form{
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    img.image-thumbnail{
      margin-right: 40px !important;
    }

    #add-group-btn{
      margin-top: 20px !important;
    }

    .fileinput-new{
      margin: 10px auto !important;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .border-button.btn-file{
      margin-left: 30px !important;
    }

    .card-footer{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #save-btn{
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

   #category-nav{
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 18px !important;
      margin-top: -20px !important;
    }


}
```

Feel free to customize the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/v3Lpoaxg/

Specifically the problem here are the round buttons, thumbnail (file input) and the save and cancel button below.

I tried to target them specifically through:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 570px) {

    #search-form{
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    img.image-thumbnail{
      margin-right: 40px !important;
    }

    #add-group-btn{
      margin-top: 20px !important;
    }

    .fileinput-new{
      margin: 10px auto !important;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .border-button.btn-file{
      margin-left: 30px !important;
    }
}
```

But still it messed up:

[image]

Comment: Please, remove from question everything that is not related to the propblem. Split the question into several separeated question if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Change structure as follows:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="edit-modal" class="modal fade" id="new-contact-modal" role="dialog"
    tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center font-weight-bold">New Contact</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Email:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="company" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Mobile:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="phone" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Phone:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Address:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="city" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">City:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="city" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">State:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="city" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Country:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="city" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Zip:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="group" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Category:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12">
                                        <select name="group" id="group" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Select category</option>
                                            <option value="1">Family</option>
                                            <option value="2">Friend</option>
                                            <option value="3">Other</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
                                        <a href="#" id="add-group-btn"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-category-button btn-block mt-0">Add Category</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row" id="add-new-group">
                                    <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-8">
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_id" pla<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="edit-modal" class="modal fade" id="new-contact-modal" role="dialog"
    tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog

    ceholder="Enter category name"
                                                    aria-label="Enter category name" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary category-btn" type="button" id="button-addon2">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                        <div class="fileinput-new img-thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="...">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists img-thumbnail"
                                            style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <span class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-button btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select
                                                    image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-button mb-3 ml-3" id="save-btn">Save</button>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-button mt-n3" data-dismiss="modal"
                                id="cancel-btn">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. modal doesn't respect responsive